# Duplicate jars in Java 11 causing below error

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, java-11, java-module

We are upgrading project from Java 8 to Java 11, and facing the below error:

```
The package javax.xml.namespace is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml
```

Apparently, this is due to same package which is existing in another jar file is creating a problem. In order to fix this issue, we have excluded the jar time temporarily and it is working fine.

Is there a way that we can ignore this error without removing the transient dependencies. Since we have 200+ services and excluding from each service is a mammoth effort.

My pom.xml as below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <mule.version>3.9.0</mule.version>
        <mule.tools.version>1.2</mule.tools.version>
        <apikit.version>3.9.0</apikit.version>
        <munit.version>1.1.0</munit.version>
        <mule.munit.support.version>3.7.1</mule.munit.support.version>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <junit.version>4.9</junit.version>
        <jackson.version>2.8.5</jackson.version>
        <httpcore.version>4.4.5</httpcore.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <finalName>somename</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: you would only need that exclusion when using modulepath, if you attempt to place all those dependencies on the classpath as you did with Java-8, things would work as usual. now if the question is if you could have better of both the worlds, you might look into things like profiles and toolchains and manage these accordingly with maven (don't have a link handy)

Comment: thanks for your comment Naman. Could you advise me how to disable modulepath and fall back like Java-8. There is absolutely no change in my pom.xml aside java version change.

Comment: did you introduce a `module-info.java` in your code? in my knowledge, maven treats projects with a module descriptor to be modularised and hence the modulepath comes into the picture.

Comment: No. I have not introduced module-info.java.

Comment: then it might be worth looking at your maven configuration including `pom.xml` and the way you are executing your service, try sharing a minimal example to reproduce in the question as you [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62913587/edit).

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62913587/edit) and update it instead of sharing the details here in the comments section.

Comment: Done. Please see the qn.

Comment: and how do you execute your project? I see `spring-boot-starter-parent` as your project's parent and it might be governing the build configurations as well.

Comment: I am running through SpringBootApplication as a stand alone jar